# Reverse Look up Django foreign key?

Tags: python, django

I have three models universities, users and master user types .Models are defined below.

university model:-

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models


# WE ARE AT MODELS/UNIVERSITIES

class Universities(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(db_column="id", max_length=11, help_text="")
    name = models.CharField(db_column="name", max_length=255, help_text="")
    abbreviation = models.CharField(db_column="abbreviation", max_length=255, help_text="")
    address = models.CharField(db_column="address", max_length=255, help_text="")
    status = models.BooleanField(db_column="status", default=False, help_text="")
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(db_column='createdAt', auto_now=True, help_text="")  
    modifiedAt = models.DateTimeField(db_column='modifiedAt', auto_now=True, help_text="")  
    updatedBy = models.IntegerField(db_column="updatedBy",default=None,help_text="Logged in user updated by ......")

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        get_latest_by = 'createdAt'
        db_table = 'universities'
```

user model:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from cms.models.masterUserTypes import MasterUserTypes
from cms.models.universities import Universities
from cms.models.departments import MasterDepartments



# WE ARE AT MODELS/APPUSERS

requestChoice = (
    ('male', 'male'),
    ('female', 'female'),
    )


class Users(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(db_column="id", max_length=11, help_text="")
    userTypeId = models.ForeignKey(MasterUserTypes, db_column="userTypeId")
    universityId = models.ForeignKey(Universities, db_column="universityId")  
    departmentId = models.ForeignKey(MasterDepartments , db_column="departmentId",help_text="")  
    name = models.CharField(db_column="name",max_length=255,help_text="")
    username = models.CharField(db_column="username",unique=True, max_length=255,help_text="")
    email = models.CharField(db_column="email",unique=True, max_length=255,help_text="")
    password = models.CharField(db_column="password",max_length=255,help_text="")
    bio = models.TextField(db_column="bio",max_length=500,help_text="")
    gender = models.CharField(db_column="gender",max_length=6, choices=requestChoice,help_text="")
    mobileNo = models.CharField(db_column='mobileNo', max_length=16,help_text="")  
    dob = models.DateField(db_column="dob",help_text="")
    major = models.CharField(db_column="major",max_length=255,help_text="")
         class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'users'
```

and user type model:-

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models

# WE ARE AT MODELS/MASTER USERS TYPES

class MasterUserTypes(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(db_column="id", max_length=11, help_text="")
    userType = models.CharField(db_column='userType', max_length=255, help_text="")
    description = models.CharField(db_column='desciption', max_length=255, help_text="")
    status = models.BooleanField(db_column="status", default=False, help_text="")
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(db_column='createdAt', auto_now=True, help_text="")  
    modifiedAt = models.DateTimeField(db_column='modifiedAt', auto_now=True, help_text="")  
    updatedBy = models.ForeignKey(User, db_column='updatedBy',
                                  help_text="Logged in user updated by ......")

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'master_user_types'
```

There are two types of user in my case one is student and other is teacher.And the tyoe is defined in MasterUserTypes model.I am finding the total users in university wise by using revser look up i am getting the toal users university wise like this:-

```
{{ item.users_set.all.count }}
```

where item is a university object passed from view as a contex.This is done by reverse lazy fetching but when i am applying conditon for user types its not working:-

```
{% if item.users_set.model.masterusertypes.id == 1  %} {{ item.users_set.all.count  }} {% else %} {{ 0 }} {% endif %}
```

i want to use reverse lazy to find out how many students are there.

Comment: what is it showing?? try to check what output it gives {{ item.users_set.model.masterusertypes.id  }}

Comment: it shows nothing..........

Comment: {{ item.users_set.masterusertypes.id }} try this once and let me know

Comment: same nothing...

Comment: what does it print for `item.users.all()`  ?

Comment: {{item.users.all}} it prints nothing but it prints  total count of the users     when I use this {{ item.users_set.all.count }} belonging to that university

Comment: {{ item.users.masterusertypes.id }} this is what you need i guess @AbiWaqas

Comment: i  need to write  if condition and want to achive something like this           {% if  item.users.masterusertypes.id ==1 %} {{ item.users.all.count}}{% endif%}